# Edit email views in shoppe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I can't seem to find the `shoppe` tag in stackoverflow.

---

I'm using [Shoppe](http://tryshoppe.com/) gem for rails.

I want to know if there is a way to edit the views for the emails that are being sent when an order is placed in shoppe.

I would like to add an attachment to the email when you accept the order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can just re-define Shoppe's mailer method:

```
module Shoppe
  class OrderMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    def received(order)
      @order = order
      attachment(content_type: 'image/jpeg', body: File.read('image.jpg'))
      mail :from => Shoppe.settings.outbound_email_address, :to => order.email_address, :subject => I18n.t('shoppe.order_mailer.received.subject', :default => "Order Confirmation")
    end
  end
end
```

Puts that somewhere into your `app/initializers`. Remember to set your content-type properly.

Comment: thanks for the info, I manage to just copy and paste the exact names of the directories and views of the gem in the rails app and that did the trick, at least for the models and mail views. But this seems like the easiest solution imo.

Comment: Just want to add that you could just fork the gem and just edit the models in there. Source: https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe/issues/250

Answer (score 1):

***This is the best and fastest solution for anyone who just wanting to change the actual text like i did.***

You can just go directly to the file of the email and edit it.  all i did was visit The exact File [Here](https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe/blob/master/app/views/shoppe/order_mailer/accepted.text.erb) and recreate that file and its path into my own application and changed the words to my pleasing.

https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe/blob/master/app/views/shoppe/order_mailer/accepted.text.erb